# virsh and creating storage pools - What is sourcepath "- - - -"

Tags: centos, virtual-machine, virsh

I am running CentOS 7 and was following a chapter in a book dealing with virtualization and creating storage pools. I successfully ran the following command, but I'm not sure what setting `- - - -` as the sourcepath actually does.

```
virsh pool-define-as rhpol_virsh dir - - - - /var/lib/libvirt/rhpol_virsh
```

Description of command: Define the storage pool as type "dir" with the source path "----" and target */var/lib/libvirt/rhpol_virsh* directory

I read the man pages and googled this topic, but I didn't find an explanation. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I am guessing it means blank source path ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A storage pool of type `dir` is a directory path. The only meaningful value is the directory path itself so all other parameters are ignored. In your example, `/var/lib/libvirt/rhpol_virsh` is a location in your filesystem that will be mapped to the storage pool `rhpol_virsh`.

Another way of viewing this command, which I prefer, is by named parameter rather than positional parameter. This also defines your pool as `rhpol_virsh` as being part of your filesystem starting at `/var/lib/libvirt/rhpol_virsh`:

```
virsh pool-define-as rhpol_virsh --type dir --target /var/lib/libvirt/rhpol_virsh
```

At the risk of over complicating matters, but trying to answer your comment questions, the man page defines positional parameters as follows:

```
pool-define-as name --print-xml type [source-host] [source-path] [source-dev] [source-name] [<target>] [--source-format format]
```

Since the pool definition doesn't need anything except `target` we need `-` placeholders to get to the `target`. Thus `pool-define-as rhpol_virsh - - - - /var/lib/libvirt/rhpol_virsh`.

Once you have defined the storage pool you need to start it:

```
virsh pool-autostart rhpol_virsh    # Start on boot
virsh pool-start rhpol_virsh        # Start now
```

You can see which storage pools are defined, and their status, with `virsh pool-list`. If you add something to a storage pool you may need to tell the `libvirt` suite that the pool contents need refreshing:

```
virsh pool-list | awk '/active/{print$1}' | xargs -n1 virsh pool-refresh
```

Comment: I understand that. But this is still confusing '- - - -' . Could it mean that the target is the same as the source ?

Comment: Iv read ur edits. A storage pool of type 'dir' only needs the relevant directory path. But I would specifically like to understand what '- - - -' means.

Comment: @Infinite I suppose you could think of it like that. But take another look at my answer, which I've updated for you

Comment: Thank u sooo much. I will mark this as answered :) :) :) :) :)